# Is the below ecommerce tracking script correct?

Tags: google-analytics

I have added the following script in my Magento website's order confirmation page, but still, I am unable to track e-commerce data. Please help me to track e-commerce data in Google Analytics.

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA 000000000-1"></script>

    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
   'thansactionId' : '<?php echo $orderId; ?>',
    'currency': 'GBP',
    'event' : 'conversion',
    'Grandtotal': '<?php echo $grandtotal; ?>',
    'status': '<?php echo "$status";?>',
    'storename': '<?php echo "$storename";?>',
    'shippingmethod': '<?php echo "$shipping";?>',
    'shippinamount': '<?php echo "$shippingamount";?>'
    });
    </script>
```

I am not using the Google Tag Manager, So I want the solution for Google Analytics only.

Comment: How do you know you cant track data?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Google Tag Manager (GTM), but you are using data format of GTM. As per [GTAG documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ecommerce), the (standard ecommerce) transaction tracking code is the following for gtag():

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162",
  "affiliation": "Google online store",
  "value": 23.07,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

You can fill in the variables from your PHP code, and optionally include product data as well.

Enhanced ecommerce format is available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_purchases).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research I have found following script for my case as I am using analytics.js for my website. Let me know is it correct or not?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-35506203-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
'currency': 'GBP'  // local currency code.
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
ga('ecommerce:send'); 
</script>
```